# AS3 BitmapData memory leaks

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, memory-leaks, bitmapdata

This is simple test on AS3 for BitmapData memory allocation.

```java
private function memoryTest(): void
{
  trace("BitmapData memory test. Create bmps..."); // First breakpoint
  var bmps:Array = new Array (1000);

  for (var i:int=0; i<1000; i++)
  {
    bmps[i] = new BitmapData(451, 451, true, 0);
    trace(i+". bmp created");
  }

  trace("All bmps created."); // Second breakpoint

  for (i=0; i<1000; i++)
  {
    bmps[i].dispose();
    bmps[i] = null;
  }
  bmps.splice(0, bmps.length);
  bmps = null;

  freeMemoryGC();

  trace("All bmps deleted.");
  trace("Test complete."); // Last breakpoint
}

private function freeMemoryGC(): void
{
  // the GC will perform a full mark/sweep on the second call.
  try
  {
    new LocalConnection().connect('foo');
    new LocalConnection().connect('foo');
  }
  catch (e:*)
  {
  }

  System.gc();
  System.gc();
}
```

There are 3 breakpoints in this test, that are commented in code. Breakpoints pause program during some time. Breakpoints correspond to the horizontal lines on this memory state chart.

[image: memory usage graph]

My question is: why not all memory was free after **dispose()** calls? What wrong in this code and how to clear **BitmapData** objects properly?

**UPDATE 1**:
I don't think that problem is in garbage collector. **dispose()** works out of GC and it should release the pixels data. Also this example should allocate 451*451*4*1000 bytes **theoretically**. But this test application allocates **25% more** bytes in **System.privateMemory** and these 25% is never released by GC and **dispose()**.

**UPDATE 2**:
If I create 13 images 4059x4059 px instead of 100 images 451x451 px, then memory allocates exactly equals to theoretical size and **memory is released properly** after call GC! I don't know why it happens.

**UPDATE3**:
Here is my results of interval test, created by Daniel MesSer in him answer:
[image: memory usage graph on interval test]

Comment: Run this test 100x times and than check . I suggest You to make interval and run this on each frame . Calling GC doesnt mean that memory will back to same state .

Comment: Interesting idea about 100x times and interval.

Comment: How are you calling `memoryTest()`? Is there anything outside of that function that is allocating memory?

Comment: You have result of inverval checking ? If memory is instantly growing , this mean that You have leak , if not , everything is fine . Do not focus on few kb leak .

Comment: I think the extra 25% might account for the internal mipmaps that are being creaated.

Comment: I think about internal mipmaps too... And no way to disable mipmapping, yes?

Comment: Daniel MesSer was created interval test in him answer. It showed that memory released correctly. So, turbosel was right.

Comment: You have a memory leak. Do you remove event listeners for timer?

Comment: Also what profiling tool are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and remove the thing about local connection in free memorygc-function. Does that solve it?

**EDIT:**

```
package nyx_gaming_group.as3_tests {
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.system.System;
import messer_entertainment.MesSerUtils;

/**
 * ...
 * @author Daniel Dahlkvist
 */
public class BitmapDataMemoryLeak extends Sprite {
    private var _bitmaps:Array;

    public function BitmapDataMemoryLeak() {
        run();
    }

    private function run():void {
        MesSerUtils.delayCall(createBitmaps, 150);
        MesSerUtils.delayCall(destroyBitmaps, 4500);
        MesSerUtils.delayCall(freeMemoryGC, 4700);
        MesSerUtils.delayCall(run, 8000);
    }

    private function createBitmaps():void {
        trace("BitmapData memory test. Create bmps..."); // First breakpoint
        _bitmaps = new Array(1000);

        for (var i:int = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            _bitmaps[i] = new BitmapData(451, 451, true, 0);
        }

        trace("All bmps created."); // Second breakpoint            
    }

    private function destroyBitmaps():void {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < _bitmaps.length; i++) {
            _bitmaps[i].dispose();
            _bitmaps[i] = null;
        }
        _bitmaps = null;

        trace("All bmps deleted.");
        trace("Test complete."); // Last breakpoint
    }

    private function freeMemoryGC():void {
        System.gc();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I tried. But without hack with local connection memory is not cleared at all. Flash player 11.1 standalone debugger, win32.

Comment: I added example code how I ran this code, for me it seems to be running okay? I added some timegaps [creates bitmaps after 150ms, then destroys them after 4500ms and forces GC to run after 4700ms]

Comment: you can find an image of my result at the following place:   http://i48.tinypic.com/m7cc5k.png

Comment: Here is [my results of your test](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/493679/interval_memory_test.png)
Very interesting.

Comment: But you can clearly see that it ain't the bitmaps, and you can clearly see that it doesnt have a memory leak. What you show is some kind of extra memory allocated when the program starts. But that memory doesnt get bigger and bigger. This could be stuff like functions, classes etc